# Does Ubuntu 12.04 support HDMI?

Tags: 12.04, hdmi

Does Ubuntu 12.04 support HDMI? For some reason it doesn't work for me.

#### Harware Details:

- Lenovo z50-70 laptop
- Intel Core i5 4210u
- Nvidia GeForce 840M (disabled in the BIOS)

Comment: Please add your hardware details.

Comment: it's a lenovo z50-70 laptop with nvidia Gt 840 and i5 4210u but recently i have disabled the dedicated graphics card from the BIOS

Comment: [edit] your question to tell us what you tried! What were the problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Ubuntu itself supports HDMI.  However, on your hardware, the HDMI port is driven by the nVidia card and the Intel drives the VGA port.

You can test this by running `sudo lshw` on your system as it is and then enabling the nVidia card again and running another `sudo lshw` and presto: an HDMI port shows up!

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: Thank's man it works after enabling the dedicated graphics card